# Elixir Ecto Changeset OR Validation

Tags: validation, elixir, ecto

I am attempting to perform a Changeset validation on either an email OR phone number, and I found a nifty OR changeset function from @Dogbert here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42212425/conditional-validation-in-ecto-for-or-1-of-2-fields-is-required) - but I cannot get my OR validation flow to work correctly.

Does anyone mind taking a quick look on why the email or phone validation is always returning a `nil` changeset?

```
  @doc false
  def changeset(%User{} = user, attrs) do
    user
    |> cast(attrs, [:email, :phone])
    |> validate_required_inclusion([:email, :phone])
    |> validate_required_inclusion_format([:email, :phone])
  end

  defp validate_required_inclusion(changeset, fields) do
    if Enum.any?(fields, &present?(changeset, &1)) do
      changeset
    else
      # Add the error to the first field only since Ecto requires a field name for each error.
      add_error(changeset, hd(fields), "One of these fields must be present: #{inspect fields}")
    end
  end

  defp present?(changeset, field) do
    value = get_field(changeset, field)
    value && value != ""
  end

  ## TODO - this doesnt work
  defp validate_required_inclusion_format(changeset, fields) do
    if Enum.member?(fields, :email) do
      value = get_field(changeset, :email)
      if value && value != "" do
        IO.inspect(value, label: "email found: ")
        changeset
        |> email_changeset()
      end
    end
    if Enum.member?(fields, :phone) do
      value = get_field(changeset, :phone)
      if value && value != "" do
        IO.inspect(value, label: "phone found: ")
        changeset
        |> phone_changeset()
      end
    end
    changeset
  end

  defp email_changeset(changeset) do
    changeset
    |> validate_required([:email])
    |> validate_format(:email, ~r/.+@.+/)
    |> unique_constraint(:email)
  end

  defp phone_changeset(changeset) do
    changeset
    |> validate_required([:phone])
    |> valid_phone(:phone)
    |> unique_constraint(:phone)
  end

  defp valid_phone(changeset, field) do
    phone = get_field(changeset, field)
    IO.inspect(phone, label: "phone: ")
    {:ok, phone_number} = ExPhoneNumber.parse(phone, "US")
    IO.inspect(phone_number, label: "ExPhoneNumber: ")
    if ExPhoneNumber.is_valid_number?(phone_number) do
      changeset
    else
      changeset
      |> add_error(field, "Invalid Phone Number")
    end
  end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not returning the modified changesets properly in `validate_required_inclusion_format`. In Elixir, the last value in a block is its return value. In if statements, the last value of both its true and false branch is its return value. If you don't have an else branch and the condition is false, the return value is `nil`.

Here's the simplest way to fix the problem: join the two top level `if` and the fallback `changeset` return with a `||`:

```
defp validate_required_inclusion_format(changeset, fields) do
  if Enum.member?(fields, :email) do
    value = get_field(changeset, :email)
    if value && value != "" do
      IO.inspect(value, label: "email found: ")
      changeset
      |> email_changeset()
    end
  end || # <- note this
  if Enum.member?(fields, :phone) do
    value = get_field(changeset, :phone)
    if value && value != "" do
      IO.inspect(value, label: "phone found: ")
      changeset
      |> phone_changeset()
    end
  end || # <- and this
  changeset
end
```

Now if the first or second `if` conditions are not met, you'll get a `nil` and the third `if` will be evaluated. If the third or fourth also not met, the final fallback `changeset` will be returned.

---

Note: the naming of this function is misleading. Unlike the function you used from my previous answer, you're not using `fields` at all here. You're better off not passing `fields` to this function and calling it something like `add_email_or_phone_changeset`, e.g.

```
if value = get_field(changeset, :email) do
   ...
end ||
if value = get_field(changeset, :phone) do
   ...
end || ...
```

Comment: "If you don't have an else branch and the condition is false, the return value is nil."  - Thank you @Dogbert.